# Google maps route click event

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When i click on the Google Map i want to add a marker to that location. This works for one exception: when i click on one of the routes i plotted it doesn't work. Because the click event is only on the map itself and not the route. But i couldn't find any click event for the route i plotted. (I checked the documentation). 
Does anyone has suggestions on how to do this?

So i need a click function for the route as well not only the map.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
placeMarker(event.latLng);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either:

1. add a click listener to the route that adds the marker
2. make the clickable property of the route false {clickable:false}.

BTW - your map doesn't work if I deny geolocation.

Comment: Thanks that worked for me `new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({                             polylineOptions: {clickable: false}};` It resets the properties of the polyline do so you have to insert the ones you want to change aswell.